# ejb injection within package

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I've got an ejb

```
@Stateless
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding = DmsExportExecutor.DEFAULT)
public class InjectedBean implements BeanInterface {
}
```

that implements interface

```
@Local
public interface BeanInterface {

public static final String DEFAULT = "package.InjectedBean";
}
```

And i'm trying to inject this into a bean, that's in exactly the same project and package. by @jndiinject annotation

```
public class AnotherBean {
@JndiInject(jndiName = BeanInterface.DEFAULT)
BeanInterface bean;
}
```

If i do that, a runtime exception is thrown.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to inject jndi dependency:     env/package.InjectedBean/bean into property package.InjectedBean. AnotherBean.bean: package.InjectedBean not bound
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Could not dereference object [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: package.InjectedBean not bound]
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: package.InjectedBean not bound
```

After refactoring my InjectedBean into another package that is even located inside of the same maven project, it starts working.

Could anyone explain why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you tried using the standard @EJB annotation ? 
   @EJB
   BeanInterface bean;
   This should do the work for you by bean type.
2. You should see if (and how) your injected bean is loaded by the EJB container at container startup 
   or using the admin gui.
3. You can always do a basic lookup:
   InitialContext().lookup("the.bean.jndi.name").

Y.Lev